# JQuery UI Autocomplete not working in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui

I am trying to implement an autocomplete in ASP.NET MVC 3, following [this post](http://flux88.com/2009/04/jquery-auto-complete-text-box-with-asp-net-mvc/)
but I really can't get it to work. I have looked at a series of other posts and blogs, but no success so far.

I have a DB table which contains regions (in Japanese), like so:

1 ハイチ; 2 ドミニカ共和国; 3 南アフリカ

basically a [key, Name] pair.

In my repository I am doing the following call:

```
public IQueryable<Region> GetAllRegions()
    {
        return db.Regions;
    }
```

Getting the raw data, which I pass to the controller, pair down the data according to input and the concatenate to a string like so:

```
    public class RegionsController : Controller
{
    Region_Repository rr = new Region_Repository();

    public string FindRegions(string q)
    {
        List<string> regions = rr.GetAllRegions().Select(r => r.Name).Where(s => s.StartsWith(q)).ToList();

        return string.Join("\n", regions);
    }

}
```

The controller when accessed via server/Regions/FindRegions/?q=ハ return a page with the single entry "ハイチ" as expected.

On the page I have a textbox with id "#NewRegion" and the script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#NewRegion").autocomplete('@Url.Action("FindRegions", "Regions")');
})
</script>
```

which I placed underneath the textbox.

I have references to JQuery and JQueryUI from Google API which work since I am executing other JQuery and using the JQueryUI datepicker successfully on this page.

I tried placing the script in a separate file and hardcoding the url as '/Regions/FindRegions', but no change. I had a look in firebug (second day only, so not very proficient at using it yet) and the script doesn't seem to get executed.
The controller is called fine when accessed via URL, but anything I enter into the textbox does not get passed to the controller...

Can anybody see anything wrong with this?

Comment: i can find that you marked the answer. were you able to solve the issue? remember how ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the dark depths of [the jQuery UI documentation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#overview), the parameter used when passing the autocomplete string to the server is called `term`, not `q`.

Update: And also, initialize with `autocomplete({source: "@(...url...)"})`.

Update 2: And also, return the type of data the Autocomplete widget expects, a JSON array of strings or a JSON array of objects.

Comment: Thanks just tried that and it doesn't make the blindest bit of difference... this is so frustrating.

Comment: Is it that it has to be Json data for remote calls? I think I just got it working. Not quite sure why I managed to make it work though... Would be good to see your answer.

Comment: Thanks, but I think that's still not it... Anyway, it's working now that I am passing it json data. Not sure why though. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working in the following way. I changed the controller to return Json data like this:

```
public ActionResult FindRegions(string term)
    {
        var regionNames = rr.GetAllRegions().Select(r => r.Name).Where(s => s.Contains(term)).ToList();

        return Json(regionNames, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

note: the AllowGet is there so I could check the result via url, so for debug only.
And the autocomplete script became:

```
$(function () {
$('#NewRegion').autocomplete({ source: '/Regions/FindRegions' } );
});
```

Now it works, but I am still not sure why.

Comment: Because you are returning JSON data. Previously you returned newline-separated strings, which the Autocomplete widget doesn't handle in any case. (Either an array of strings or an array of objects.)

Comment: Ah, all makes sense now! If you put that in your answer I'd happily give it a tick.

Comment: Cool, I give you the tick then :o)